# Is there a way to normalize a set of values with only one iteration?

Tags: algorithm, normalize

So say I have a big list of floats, and I'd like to normalize them all to values between `min` and `max`. E.g. `{2, 5, 10}` with `min = 0` and `max = 2` results in a set of `{0.4, 1, 2}`.

My current algorithm for this is

1. Iterate through all elements and find the sum of the set
2. Iterate through all elements again, and divide by the sum (accounting for min and max)

My question is a general algorithmic one - is it possible to do this operation in `O(n)` instead of `O(2n)`?

Comment: I do believe a short code snippet is more powerful than your introduction -- at least for me.

Comment: Since your definition of normalization relies on the sum of the set, I don't really see how it could be possible to do it in a single iteration, as it would require you to know the future.

Comment: The algorithm does not match to the description. The result does match if you find the max and then [0,2] is mapped to [0, max].

Comment: Computing the sum is of no use, what you need is the smallest and largest values in the list.

Comment: Why this requirement of using a single pass ? (Which by the way does not change the asymptotic complexity, still O(N)).

Answer (score 5):

first, `O(n)=O(2n)`, It is an asymptotic analysis.
Back to your problem, you can do as following:

1. Iterate through all elements and find the min/max of the set
2. Use lazy evaluation technique: don't iterate through all elements again. When you will be asked for an object `i` from the set, return it through the normalization function you calculated in 1.

Notice that you can't avoid the 2-times-read for each element in the set.

Comment: This algorithm would produce {0, 0.75, 2}. Seans algorithm is your algorithm, but the minimum of the set is always 0 (and the numbers all positive). I agree that there should be no one-pass-solution

Comment: Using lazy evaluation is indeed a good idea if using a second loop is absolutely excluded for some reason (?). In the long run, if you perform N accesses or more, the total cost is higher as you need to test a flag telling if the data has already been normalized, or re-normalize it on every access.

Comment: @avim: I am not sure the OP is aware :)

Answer (score 2):

This question is ill-stated, as `O(N)` and `O(2N)` are strictly equivalent.

Assuming that what the OP is asking is a single-pass algorithm, the answer is a clear no. The normalization function, whatever it is, will depend on all values in the list so that all values must be read at least once before normalization can start, and at least one full pass is needed. In a way, that would mean that you could normalize the first element immediately, without looking at the others.

The only thing that can be gained is to normalize the values only when they are used (see @avim's answer), instead of once for all.

Technically speaking, this brings the asymptotic complexity to `O(N + M)` where `M` is the number of uses of a normalized value. If `M` exceeds `N`, this approach is more costly.